# Beginner with CSS style=border

Tags: css, border

I'm learning CSS and I have a little problem. How do I write best two border styles?

```
<h2 style="border-left: Gray 10px solid" style="boder-top: Gray 10px solid">
```

I don't know I have tried and experimented.

Comment: Do it like your Username say. Suche! This is an easy-google-question...

Comment: :D :D Jeah but i can ask here. Its not sooooo bad ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you write them in an external stylesheet. But when you want to write them inline, the following would be right:

```
<h2 style="border-left:Gray 10px solid; border-top:Gray 10px solid;"></h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for the really fast answer. I think you mean that ... 

    <link href="design.cc" type=text/css rel="stylesheet">

A extern stylesheet? hmm jeah but its not working ... Im learning jeah :D

Comment: Yes that is how you link an external stylesheet

Comment: I have created a design.css have write
 h3 {
 color: Yellow;
 background-color: Black;
}
In this Data and its not work?

Comment: you have linked it in the header? you have checked that the path in the href is right?

Comment: Jeah i think :D
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
h2 {
 color: Blue;
 }
-->
</style>
<link href="design.css" type=text/css rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test-Seite-2</title>

</head>

Comment: put the text/css also in quotation marks. So the css file is in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: Jeah in the same folder

Comment: and it must be a self closing tag. meaning the end of the tag like this <link ..... />

Comment: Im Stupid :D i have forget it. Thank you, thank you. Now its work

Answer (score 2):

```
border-left:10px solid blue;

border-top:10px solid #ddd;

border-bottom:10px dashed #ff0000;

border-right:10px dotted #00ff00;
```

[Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/border.php)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly spelling is important. Check the spelling for 'border'

You can do something like this

```
<h2 style="border-left: gray 10px solid; border-top: gray 10px solid">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 style="border-left:10px solid #000;border-top:10px solid #000;border-bottom:10px solid #000;border-right:10px solid #000;">
    Hiiiiiii
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two "style" in one element, there can be only one "style" attribute.

You can make it like this:

```
border-width: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-color: red green blue yellow;
border-style: solid solid dotted dotted;
```

Order is top - right - bottom - left.

```
style="border-width: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border-color: red green blue yellow; border-style: solid solid dotted dotted;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a very good question.  You several options.  To make the change that specific H2 element you would do the following:

```
<h2 style="border-left: Gray 10px solid; border-top: Gray 10px solid;">
    Hello World!
</h2>
```

This works for just this element.  If you want to repeat this style for unique elements on several different pages then you would use a CSS style sheet:

```
#useId {
    border-left: Gray 10px solid;
    border-top: Gray 10px solid;
}
```

Then you can add the HTML tag:

```
<h2 id="useId">
    Hello World!
</h2>
```

Then you have the ability to add this style to one or more elements on a page.  This would be done by using a css class.

```
.useClass {
    border-left: Gray 10px solid;
    border-top: Gray 10px solid;
}
```

With a class you can add the "useClass" to any element on the page to get that style.

```
<h2 class="useClass">
    Hello World!
</h2>
```